# How does the Hunter Rank Range work?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

When making a Hunters Hub, it's possible to specify a minimum and maximum HR for hunters who are allowed to enter. However, I've never seen it work, with HR 1 hunters being able to join my Hubs with 4 or 5 as a minimum requirement. Is that not how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *just* noticed the "Apply Range" setting when making a room. Unless this is set to "Yes", the range won't be applied. Kinda weird if you ask me, but it turns out I was just blind.

Comment: They must have separated them so that you can have a suggest range without enforcing it. Still weird.